# How to update multiple Wordpress postmeta based on post title

Tags: mysql, wordpress

heres the challange,

Have thousands of coupons on a Wordpress site with Woocommerce. Now i should update a postmeta field on thousands of coupons based on the coupon code (have a list of coupon codes that needs to be updated, which is 'post_title' in wp_posts table ).

Whats the best solution to do this? Do i need to Join the tables to be able to query the wp_postmeta table fields based on wp_posts table fields? If Yes how i can do that?

Also if thats done, can i update the meta fields in chunks somehow to avoid the MYSQL heavy loading?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?